# highcharts line and column - line not rendering

Tags: charts, highcharts, combinations

For the life of me, I cannot figure out why the LINE graph is not rendering.  It renders the COLUMNs just fine.  Here are my chart options. Can someone shed some light on this?
thanks.

```
    {
  'chart':
    {'renderTo': 'container'}
  ,
  'credits':
    {'text': ''},
  'title':
    {'text': 'CC SLA Attainment Trend'},
  'subtitle':
    {'text': '2013-06-01 to 2013-12-31'},
  'xAxis':
    {'categories':['Jun2013', 'Jul2013', 'Aug2013', 'Sep2013', 'Oct2013', 'Nov2013',   'Dec2013'],
    'labels':{'enabled': true} },
  'yAxis':
    {'min': 0, 'max': 100,
    'title': {'text': 'CC Attainment (percentage)'},
  'labels': {'format': '{value}%'} },
  'legend': {'enabled': true},
  'tooltip': {'pointFormat': '<b>{point.y:.2f}%<\/b>'},
  'lang': {'noData': 'There were no results based on search criteria, try again.'},
  'noData': {'style':{'fontWeight': 'bold', 'fontSize': '15px', 'color': '#C7C7C7'} },
  'navigation': {'buttonOptions':{'enabled': true} },
  'exporting': {'filename': 'CCSLAAttainment'},
  'series':[
    {'type': 'column', 'name': 'Attainment', 'dataLabels':{'enabled': true},
    'data':[73.39, 77.33, 77.52, 70.58, 68.95, 70.07, 73.58]},
    {'type': 'line', 'name': 'Objective 70.00%', 'dataLabels':{'enabled': false},
    'data':[70.00, 70.00, 70.00, 70.00, 70.00, 70.00, 70.00]}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Maybe you have some old and buggy version of Highcharts? Just tested on jsFiddle, and it works fine, see: http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/138/

Comment: OK, I downloaded and reinstalled the latest and it works. I also cleaned out browser history and cache, so maybe that was part of the issue.  Thanks.